# Connecting Dell U2715H to 13" MacBook Pro (mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm new to this area and slightly baffled. I've just bought a Dell Ultrasharp U2715H display to connect to my 13 inch mid 2012 MBP. I just need it as a bigger monitor for word docs and web sites. I might later upgrade to the latest 13 inch MBP but for now I've no idea how to set up the monitor.

I've bought a mini displayport male to HDMI female 4kx2k adapter to use with an HDMI cable but it's not working very well (nothing usable). My MBP is running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6 and the graphics card looks to be Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536MD. I've 4GB of memory installed.

I've hunted around and tried to google a route through this but I'm not technical enough. I just want the cheapest, easiest way to get this monitor up and running.

How can I connect my 13" MacBook Pro (mid 2012) to my Dell U2715H display?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an HDMI to HDMI cable (or other) to check that the combination cable you are using isn't broken in some way.

I have a new (mid-2017) MacBook Pro 13" with touchbar and found that certain combinations just don't work when I connect to the same version Dell monitor. For example I bought a USB C to HDMI cable link [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B06XXVSK7Q?ref_=pe_2105081_90912491_E_CReturnsRefundConfirmation_Asin_Title), and it will not work. I'm not technical either but believe it or not, there are different USB C settings! The website now says their new cable doesn't work with MacBook 2017 models, after I informed them. They said that they will now produce one that will.

Therefore, if changing the cable  (borrow one from a friend for an hour) doesn't cure your problem then you may be experiencing similar issues to mine.

Additionally, you now have information to avoid my mistake if you buy a new MBP and use your Dell monitor :-)

Hope this helps.